# Based on multiple parameters report has to split to multiple reports in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I'm new to crystal reports. I have a problem of generating a report, I have multiple parameters in my parameter field, If i select one parameter i will get data perfect but If i select two parameters then how can i generate two reports separately.
Ex: Select ID:**1,2**

Report 1: ID=1

1. ABC
2. DEF
3. ABCD

Report 2: ID=2

1. 1234
2. 7898
3. 9848

Like these i need to generate one by one in my report

Answer (score 0):

You can create a report with subreports and suppress the subreports based on the parameter value. If Parameter value has 1, subreport 1 is not suppressed , otherwise it will surpressed, value 2 will control subreport 2 etc. This will work in case you want to run different reports based on parameter values

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you need report bursting functionality. You can do this in code by looping through the list of values and exporting. Or you can get a 3rd-party tool that provides report bursting functionality. See a list of 3rd-party Crystal report automation tools [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#desktopsched).